# How to display a string and a number on the same line and use if statements in TI-Basic

Tags: java, ti-basic

EDIT: I found the answer! I commented it below

I have a TI-84 Plus C Silver Edition
So this is my code:

```
Prompt A,B,C
((-B+√(B²-4AC))/(2A))->X
((-B-√(B²-4AC))/(2A))->Y
Disp X,Y
```

So that works completely fine, but I want to add code at the end that works like this(This is how I would write it in Java):

```
if(X % 1 == 0 && Y % 1 == 0){
    System.out.println("(x-" + X + ")(x-" + Y + ")");
}
```

But I don't know how to format that, or even get the disp statement working, because it throws an error(data type or something).
It's not really required, but I atleast want to learn how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

So when I try this code:

```
disp "(x-" +X+ ")(x-" +Y+ ")"
```

It returns an error:
"ERROR: DATA TYPE
Wrong value or variable type entered.
Ex: Attempted to store a matrix to a list."

So I get that it's looking for only a string or only a number, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is the data type of your variables and please provide more details about the error?

Comment: `X % 1 == 0` will be `true` for all integer `X`.

Comment: @MathewsMathai I added some more details about the error in the post.

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes my goal was for that line to only run if there are integers

Comment: @MikeCAT Like it wouldn't make sense to have (x-2.321782317893278)(x-3.42784237894237) as factored form, but (x-1)(x-5) would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after a google search, I found the answer
You have to convert the number to a string(http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/number-to-string), and then you can concatenate the strings normally in the disp command.
Ex:

```
disp "(x-"+Str1+")(x-"+Str2+")"
```